# Why is the cross section's unit Barn particularly equal to $10^{-28} m^2$?

Tags: units

Why is the microscopic cross-section's unit Barn particularly equal to $10^{-28}  m^2$. Is there any history or reason behind that?

Comment: Have you read the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_(unit))? It's explained there...

Comment: If you looked at the etymology section on Wikipedia you'd find your answer, along with http://ed.fnal.gov/painless/pdfs/cross.pdf which they reference which is a great article on the matter. Also note this question is more appropriate for the history of math and science SE.

Comment: I think this is [off topic here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic), but would potentially fit on [hsm.SE].